# jar-with-dependencies not include external repositories

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to do an executable jar with my `pom.xml`, but the couchbase external repository is not included.

Everything is running ok in Eclipse. I have the couchbase client in the pom via:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>couchbase</id>
        <name>Couchbase Maven Repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

...

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>couchbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>couchbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the plugin:

```xml
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
       <archive>
         <manifest>
           <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
         </manifest>
       </archive>
       <descriptorRefs>
         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
       </descriptorRefs>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
         <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
         <goals>
           <goal>single</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
```

But `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` is included in the jar, but `com.couchbase.client`... not

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove scope "provided" from couchbase-client dependency. This is an indication for assembly-plugin not to include this dependency cause it will be provided at runtime anyway

Answer (score 0):

You defined the scope of couchbase-client as "provided" which means: you need it at compile time but you don't need to deploy it, since wherever the code runs, the necessary classes are already there (e.g. Java EE API classes when you run a Java EE application in a Java EE application server).

So the question is: is the scope "provided" correct?